# How tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: is supposed to be used?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

The master-detail project created by XCode wizard contains implementation of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` that calls `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`, then calls own custom method `configureCell` to fill the cell controls with valid data, and then returns the cell to caller. As I understand, this is how table knows how to draw its cells content.

What I don't understand is how to use it when I want to get cell from my code. And is it even supposed to be called by my code, or is it only a callback used by table framework itself?

For example, if I just want to change text of one label in cell, I thought I can just call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, and change what I need in the resulting cell object controls. But calling `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` actually makes a new cell object (probably reusing one from pool of unused cell objects) and fill ALL controls like imageviews and labels in it with data. This does not look good to me regarding to performance, when I want change just one label.

So maybe I could remove `configureCell` out of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? But then how to ensure all cell contents will be redrawn by system when `[table reloadData]` is called?

P.S.
XCode 7 wizard created this kind of code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell withObject:object];
    return cell;
}

// Then later in controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] withObject:anObject];
        break;
```

`configureCell` is called twice here. Seems like non-sense to me. I hoped at least people who write code for wizards understand how this is supposed to be working.

Comment: this call is only used by the table framework. you can call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths and send only one row to update a particular row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two different methods being called here that have similar names.

`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is a `UITableViewDataSource` method that you implement to create the cell for the table to show.  The tableview calls this method when a new cell is going to come on screen.

`controller:didChange:...` is calling a different method called `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` which is a `UITableView` method.  This method queries the table for a cell that is already being displayed after previously being created using the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` datasource method and doesn't result in it being called again.  It's calling this method to access the already displayed cell and update it with new info when the object changes.

Both calls to `configureCell` are necessary.

Comment: My bad, method names are too similar, I didn't see they actually different. Now it makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: But why both calls to configureCell are necessary here? Isn't the second one overwrites all that was done by the first one?

Comment: The second one is only called when an object changes so you want to overwrite the data currently in the cell with the data from the updated object.

Comment: Yes, but I mean in context of NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate event one call to configureCell with the updated object would be enough.

Comment: Right, it only calls `configureCell` once when it gets the update notification.